# Find an example of three groups $E < F < G$ where $E$ is normal in $F$ and $F$ is normal in $G$ but $E$ is not normal in $G$

Tags: group-theory

> Find an example of three groups $E < F < G$ where $E$ is normal in $F$ and $F$ is normal in $G$ but $E$ is not normal in $G$.

I am looking to prove this case by giving an example, and I am not sure how to proceed. I need help!

Comment: what groups are you familiar with in which you know almost all normal subgroups... ?

Comment: "why up-vote when OP has not showed what he has tried?" Quoted from some other Question :P

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at $G = S^4$. Let E be the subgroup generated by one pair of disjoint transpositions, i.e. $E = <(12)(34)>$. Let F be the subgroup generated by all pairs of disjoint transpositions, i.e. $F = <(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)>$. Try to show that E is normal in F, and that F is normal in G, but E is not normal in G.

Comment: This is a nice example!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Look at $D_4$, the dinedral group of order 8, and find a non-central element of order2. Now use the fact that any subgroup of index 2 is normal.